# ArrayList of serializable objects as intent extra not received by broadcast receivers

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am sending a broadcast with the intent containing an ArrayList of serialized objects as a intent extra.

When this arrayList contains about 500 valid objects, this is not being received by the onReceive() of the broadcast receiver. But with about 100 objects, I am able to get the ArrayList in onReceive()

Is there a known limit for the amount of data that can be received/sent using intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea to pass a big amount of data through intent. The data passed through intents must be small.

I see 3 solutions:

- Good: I suggest you to **store your objects in a db** and then **pass the ids** through your intent.
- Medium: make a singleton (with Application class & put your list in the static instance)
- Bad & **not** recommended: make your list static & pass the ids (or positions).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But is there a limit? Is the object silently discarded? I don't believe so.